# env file-named volume in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker. I am writing a docker-compose file which creates 2 containers, *foo* and *bar*, sharing a volume *data*:

```
services:

    foo:
        container_name: foo
        build: ./foo
        volumes:
            - data:/var/lib/

    bar:
        container_name: bar
        build: ./bar
        volumes:
            - data:/var/lib/
        depends_on:
            - foo

volumes:
    data:
```

Now, I want to use the environment variable *TAG*, to tag containers and volumes, in order to specify if it's for *test* or *production*. I expects something like this:

```
services:

    foo:
        container_name: foo_${TAG}
        build: ./foo
        volumes:
            - data_${TAG}:/var/lib/

    bar:
        container_name: bar_${TAG}
        build: ./bar
        volumes:
            - data_${TAG}:/var/lib/
        depends_on:
            - foo

volumes:
    data_${TAG}:
```

Obviously, docker-compose is unhappy because of the last line containing `data_${TAG}:`.

How can I name my volume with *TAG* env variable?

Comment: Can you create your volumes in advance (aka compose external volumes)? If so, there's an easy solution to this.

Comment: One of the volumes is an Apache log file, so I think I can't create them in advance. What is your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your volumes in advance, you can use the variable on external volume names like this (note that the reference inside of compose is a fixed name but it points to a variable external volume name):

```
$ cat docker-compose.volvar.yml
version: '2'

volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: test-data-${TAG}

services:
  source:
    image: busybox
    command: /bin/sh -c 'echo From ${TAG} >>/data/common.log && sleep 10m'
    environment:
    - TAG
    volumes:
    - data:/data
  target:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /data/common.log
    depends_on:
    - source
    environment:
    - TAG
    volumes:
    - data:/data
```

Create your volumes in advance with a `docker volume create` command:

```
$ docker volume create test-data-dev
test-data-dev

$ docker volume create test-data-uat
test-data-uat

$ docker volume create test-data-stage
test-data-stage
```

And here's an example of running it (I didn't use different directories or change the project name, so compose just replaced my containers each time, but I could have easily changed the project to run them all concurrently with the same results):

```
$ TAG=dev docker-compose -f docker-compose.volvar.yml up -d
Creating test_source_1
Creating test_target_1

$ docker logs test_target_1
From dev

$ TAG=uat docker-compose -f docker-compose.volvar.yml up -d
Recreating test_source_1
Recreating test_target_1

$ docker logs test_target_1
From uat

$ TAG=stage docker-compose -f docker-compose.volvar.yml up -d
Recreating test_source_1
Recreating test_target_1

$ docker logs test_target_1
From stage

$ # just to show that the volumes are saved and unique,
$ # rerunning uat generates a second line
$ TAG=uat docker-compose -f docker-compose.volvar.yml up -d
Recreating test_source_1
Recreating test_target_1

$ docker logs test_target_1
From uat
From uat
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible like that but here is what I do:

I have a docker-compose.yml file like that

```
services:

    foo:
        container_name: foo_${TAG}
        build: ./foo
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/

    bar:
        container_name: bar_${TAG}
        build: ./bar
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/
        depends_on:
            - foo
```

And then I create a file docker-compose.override.yml that contains

```
services:

    foo:
        volumes:
            - data_dev:/var/lib/

    bar:
        volumes:
            - data_dev:/var/lib/
```

This way when you launch docker-compose, it will use the main file and use the other file to override its values.

You should then have 3 files:

- docker-compose.yml
- docker-compose.override-prod.yml
- docker-compose.override-dev.yml

And then when you build you have the choice between those 2:

1. (What I do) I copy docker-compose.override-.yml to docker-compose.override.yml and Docker Compose with automatically takes those 2 files
2. You can provide the 2 files to use to the docker compose file (I forgot what the paramter is... I guess it's "-f")

I hope it helps